# how do i popup div tags using javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

hi i have a situation that i want to put popup code in if else statement using JavaScript? my code is

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(documnet).ready(function () {
    $("#AddToCartBtn").click(function (e) {
        ShowDialog(false);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#AddToCartBtn").click(function (e) {
        ShowDialog(true);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#btnClose").click(function (e) {
        HideDialog();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
        var brand = $("#brands input:radio:checked").val();
        $("#output").html("<b>Your favorite mobile brand: </b>" + brand);
        HideDialog();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});

function ShowDialog() {
    $("#overlay").show();
    $("#dialog").fadeIn(300);


    if (modal) {
        $("#overlay").unbind("click");
    }
    else {
        $("#overlay").click(function (e) {
            HideDialog();
        });
    }
}

function HideDialog() {
    $("#overlay").hide();
    $("#dialog").fadeOut(300);
}
```

Heres the css..

```
.web_dialog_overlay
{
position: fixed;
top: 0;


 right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background: #000000;
   opacity: .15;
   filter: alpha(opacity=15);
   -moz-opacity: .15;
   z-index: 101;
   display: none;
}
.web_dialog
{
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   width: 380px;
   height: 200px;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -190px;
   margin-top: -100px;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   border: 2px solid #336699;
   padding: 0px;
   z-index: 102;
   font-family: Verdana;
   font-size: 10pt;
}
.web_dialog_title
{
   border-bottom: solid 2px #336699;
   background-color: #336699;
   padding: 4px;
   color: White;
   font-weight:bold;
}
.web_dialog_title a
{
   color: White;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.align_right
{
   text-align: right;
}
```

and lastly the asp button control and the 's

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="AddToCartBtn" runat="server" RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>'
                                        ImageUrl="~/Pictures/ShoppingCart.png" onClientClick="ShowDialog()"                                         
                                          />

<div id="output"></div>

<div id="overlay" runat="server" class="web_dialog_overlay"></div>

<div id="dialog" class="web_dialog">


<table style="width: 100%; border: 0px;" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
         <td class="web_dialog_title">Online Survey</td>
         <td class="web_dialog_title align_right">
            <a href="#" id="btnClose">Close</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 15px;">
            <b>Choose your favorite mobile brand? </b>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 15px;">
            <div id="brands">
               <input id="brand1" name="brand" type="radio" checked="checked" value="Nokia" /> Nokia
               <input id="brand2" name="brand" type="radio" value="Sony" /> Sony 
               <input id="brand3" name="brand" type="radio" value="Motorola" /> Motorola
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
            <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

as same as it but here when user clicks add to cart it will add to whistlist but for me when i click add to cart popup div has to display

Answer (score 0):

I usually set a global value that would be set up in the view and then use that in the javascript action.

for example just put something like that in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.showPopup=@(ViewBag.showPopup);
</script>
```

and in javascript file:

```
var showPopup;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#AddToCartBtn").click(function (e) {
        if(window.showPopup=1){
            ShowDialog(true);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion sir but can you explain  deeply so that i can understand

Comment: like i have a button "add fav" when i click that i should popup with login div

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to have two event handlers for the same AddToCartBtn click?  They will both run at basically the same time, unpredictable which finishes last.